# Android, Java, Get data from a web form dropdown via Jsoup

Tags: java, android, webforms, jsoup, html-parsing

With Android Studio and Java, I've tried almost everything I've found about it on StackOverflow but nothing has worked for me, I don't know how to extract the values from a dropdown list in web:
(https://icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es/icpplus/index.html)

```html
<select id="form" name="form" autocomplete="address-level1">
<option value="">Seleccionar ...</option>
<option value="/icpplus/citar?p=15&amp;locale=es&amp;appkey=null">A Coruña</option>
<option value="/icpplus/citar?p=2&amp;locale=es&amp;appkey=null">Albacete</option>
<option value="/icpco/citar?p=3&amp;locale=es&amp;appkey=null">Alicante</option>
...
</select>
```

And my code in Android Studio, onCreate void:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("https://icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es/icpplus/index.html");
if(doc != null){
    Elements elements = doc.select("form");
    int length1 = elements.toString().length();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("%s", length1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    /*for(Element elem : elements) {
        text += elem.text();
    }*/
}
```

It always gives me a length of 0, so I imagine it returns nothing.
What's in the for loop doesn't give me anything either.
How should I do to get all the values (`/icpplus/citar...` etc) and all the names (`A Coruña, Albacete...` etc)?
Thank you so much.

I have tried Jsoup.connect and the application closes directly.
I have also tried:
`doc.select("select[id=form]");`, `doc.select("#form");`
It doesn't work either

Comment: Open a browser in your PC, not the mobile device, disable Javascript in the browser and go to that site, check if the browser displays the data that you are looking for.

Comment: On the web I get a message saying that JavaScript is needed to work properly, but the dropdown and dropdown list do show up.

Comment: I cannot open that page in my browser, so I cannot help you any further.